# How to scan and print from terminal

Tags: printing

I want to scan a file from terminal.  What is the command for that?  I also want to print the same file on a different printer, thus making a copier.  I want to put it together into a shell script. I know how to make a script, but I need the commands.

Edit 1: the scanner is usb and the printer is LAN and setup with CUPS.

Edit 2: I want the script to scan and print the document.

Comment: Having a quick look using auto-complete in the terminal I found the `scanimage` command which may be useful for what you want. I haven't had any experience with the command myself but the man page seems to suggest that it is a command-line interface for scanning images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Scanning**

```
scanimage > image.png
```

More info `man scanimage`

**Printing**

Connect your printer through usb, and do `lsusb` to find under what name it is reported to the system. For example I have Desjet_F4200.

Next, `lp /path/to/your/file  -d Deskjet_`   and double-tap TAB button to complete the name. You can always turn this into a script instead of typing printer name every time:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Author:Sergiy
# Description: script to print 1 inch margin documents


lp $*  -d Deskjet_F4200 -o page-bottom=72 -o page-top=72 -o page-left=72 -o page-right=72
```

Comment: My printer is connected through LAN (plugged into the router)

Comment: In that case, you may find this useful: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu

Comment: I can already print from the gui with the network printer.  I set all that up with CUPS.

Comment: By the way, add this information to your question, so others can see it. For next time you ask a question, remember to add all the related information there

Comment: Found something else: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems

Comment: How do I find out my printer name on the LAN?

Answer (score 0):

On my system I can use this address

> printername:net:ip-address

Example:
`Deskjet_F4200:net:192.168.1.2`